# Doing full text string search in PostgreSQL Ecto Elixir

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

My question is more about Database but it includes Elixir and Ecto thats why am posting it heare instead of DB forum on StackExchange.

We have a table of Camera Actitvies in our PG database.

which have columns like that

```
  id serial NOT NULL,
  camera_id integer NOT NULL,
  access_token_id integer,
  action text NOT NULL,
  done_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  ip inet,
  extra json,
  camera_exid text,
  name text
```

And we 2 reports for showing data from this table.. in the first one we get the data with `camera_id` and Also we have an index on it as

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX camera_activities_camera_id_done_at_index
  ON camera_activities
  USING btree
  (camera_id, done_at);
```

On that report, everything is working fine. But on the other hand. we are getting results on the basis of filed `name`.
What I am doing,

```
  def for_a_user(full_name, from, to, types) do
    CameraActivity
    |> where(name: ^full_name)
    |> where([c], c.done_at >= ^from and c.done_at <= ^to)
    |> with_types_if_specified(types)
    |> order_by([c], desc: c.done_at)
    |> SnapshotRepo.all
  end
```

But its timed out.

How can we handle this fulltext search for millions of records?

Comment: you sure `where(name: ^full_name)` is for FTS and just `like`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun `where(name: ^full_name)` will do `WHERE table.name = 'foo'` if full_name is `foo` if that's what you were asking.

Comment: ah. full text string confused me to think you want a `full text search` index. If you want to speed up `WHERE table.name = 'foo'` just create an index on the field `name`, like `create index xxx on on camera_activities(name);`. Of course if you can afford it

Comment: Could this be any possibility to solve this issue as `|> where([c], fragment("to_tsvector(?) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", c.name, ^full_name))`

Comment: Is the index you posted the only one you have on the table? It doesn't seem to include `full_name`. Also since the index you have mentioned has `done_at` as the second element of the tuple, it doesn't work as a standalone index on `done_at`.